# Pandas - Pivot and Rearrange Table With Multiple Labels in Same Header

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, header, reformatting

I have an xlsx file with tabs for multiple years of data. Each tab contains a table with many columns and the table is structured like this:

```
+-----------+-------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|   City    | State | Number of Drivers, 2019 | Number of Cars, 2019 |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| LA        | CA    |                     123 |                 10.0 |
| San Diego | CA    |                     456 |                 2345 |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

I would like to rearrange the table to look like this, and do it for each tab in the xlsx:

```
+-----------+-------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|   City    | State | Year |   Measure Name    | Measure Value |
+-----------+-------+------+-------------------+---------------+
| LA        | CA    | 2019 | Number of Drivers |           123 |
| San Diego | CA    | 2019 | Number of Drivers |           456 |
| LA        | CA    | 2019 | Number of Cars    |            10 |
| San Diego | CA    | 2019 | Number of Cars    |          2345 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------------------+---------------+
```

There are a lot of moving pieces to this and has been a little tricky to get the final formatting correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do `melt` then `join` with `str.split`

```
s=df.melt(['City','State'])
s=s.join(s.variable.str.split(',',expand=True))
Out[120]: 
       City State              variable   value                0     1
0        LA    CA  NumberofDrivers,2019   123.0  NumberofDrivers  2019
1  SanDiego    CA  NumberofDrivers,2019   456.0  NumberofDrivers  2019
2        LA    CA     NumberofCars,2019    10.0     NumberofCars  2019
3  SanDiego    CA     NumberofCars,2019  2345.0     NumberofCars  2019

# if you need change the name adding .rename(columns={}) at the end
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! Below I'll add the code to perform the table rearrangement on all of the tabs in the xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I wwas able to apply Yoben's solution to every tab in the xlsx file, append them together and write the full table to a .csv:

```
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

full_table = pd.DataFrame()
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet['sheet'] = name
    sheet = sheet.melt(['City','State'])
    sheet = sheet.join(sheet.variable.str.split(',' , expand=True))
    full_table = full_table.append(sheet)


full_table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)


full_table.to_csv('Full Table.csv')
```